# Where to add new marker variable when Google Maps have geolocation?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want people to see nearest places to them that were added by me.
Is it possible to style the marker sign?

```
 var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
// This is my attempt to put a marker with some info START//
    var map;
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-59.389, 24.806);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


//----------------------END----------------------//

window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple markers in google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579186/multiple-markers-in-google-map)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In relation to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579186/multiple-markers-in-google-map), you can add a marker by calling the **`google.maps.Marker`** constructor and specify the `position` and `map` fields.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
});
```

See full guide [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple). You can then [customize a marker image](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons) by defining an icon to show instead of the default marker image.

You can start off with this **[example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)** which displays customized markers to indicate locations near a specified address.

Hope this helps!